# Adapt windows-style VBA code for UNIX-style text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have my previous code as below running perfectly on DOS txt file type ending in end-of-line decimal value = 13, however I have to use the same code in Unix txt file, I tried to change the end-of-line decimal value = 10 and the For loop that counts Rowcount / Colcnt works, but during the array transpose Subscript our of range error occurs at the beginning of the loop at DataOut(RowCnt, cnt) = Line(cnt)

```
    ' // Convert the bytes into a string.
    Text = StrConv(DataIn, vbUnicode)

    ' // Create an array of the lines.
    Lines = Split(Text, vbCrLf)

    ' // Dimension the transpose array.
    ReDim DataOut(RowCnt, ColCnt)

    ' // fill the transpose array.
    For RowCnt = 0 To UBound(DataOut, 1)
        Line = Split(Lines(RowCnt), Delimiter)
        For cnt = 0 To UBound(Line)
            DataOut(RowCnt, cnt) = Line(cnt)
        Next cnt
    Next RowCnt
```

---

Whole VBA code:

```
Dim ColCnt      As Long
Dim cnt       As Long
Dim DataIn()    As Byte
Dim DataOut     As Variant
Dim Delimiter   As String
Dim File        As String
Dim Line        As Variant
Dim Lines       As Variant
Dim RngOut      As Range
Dim RowCnt      As Long
Dim Text        As String
Dim Wks         As Worksheet

   
    ' // Use the ActiveSheet. You specifiy any sheet you want here.
    Set Wks = Worksheets.add
    
    
    ' // Starting cell for output.
    Set RngOut = Wks.Range("A1")
    
    File = "C:\jmp\P33A120200704.txt"
    
    ' // Character that separates the data fields.
    Delimiter = ","
    
        ' // Read the whole file into memory as byte data.
        Open File For Binary Access Read As #1
            ReDim DataIn(LOF(1))
            Get #1, , DataIn
        Close #1
        
        ' // Find the rows and the greastest column width needed for the transpose array.
        For n = 0 To UBound(DataIn, 1) - 1
            ' // Is this byte a delimiter?
            If DataIn(n) = Asc(Delimiter) Then cnt = cnt + 1 ' Count the number of columns in this line.
            
            '// Is this the end of the line? 13 is the value for DOS
            If DataIn(n) = 10 Then
                ' // Save the greatest number of columns found.
                If cnt > ColCnt Then ColCnt = cnt
                cnt = 0                 ' Reset the line column count.
                RowCnt = RowCnt + 1     ' Increase the row count.
            End If
            
            Debug.Assert n < 1255730
            
        Next n
        
        ' // Convert the bytes into a string.
        Text = StrConv(DataIn, vbUnicode)
        
        ' // Create an array of the lines.
        Lines = Split(Text, vbCrLf)
        
        ' // Dimension the transpose array.
        ReDim DataOut(RowCnt, ColCnt)
        
        ' // fill the transpose array.
        For RowCnt = 0 To UBound(DataOut, 1)
            Line = Split(Lines(RowCnt), Delimiter)
            For cnt = 0 To UBound(Line)
                DataOut(RowCnt, cnt) = Line(cnt)
            Next cnt
        Next RowCnt
        
        ' // Output the array to the worksheet.
        RngOut.Resize(RowCnt, ColCnt + 1).Value = DataOut
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Unix, make this change:

```
 ' // Create an array of the lines.
    Lines = Split(Text, vbLf)
```

The EOL character for Unix is just the `LF`.

If you examine the Locals window when the error appears, you will understand better what is going on.